# What happens when I write to a random memory address?

Tags: rust

```
extern crate core;
use core::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

struct MutPtr<T>{
    ptr: *mut T
}
impl<T> MutPtr<T>{
    fn new(value: &mut T) -> MutPtr<T>{
        MutPtr{ptr: value} 
    }
}
impl<T> Deref for MutPtr<T>{
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &T{
        unsafe{
            &(*self.ptr)
        }
    }
}
impl<T> DerefMut for MutPtr<T>{
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T{
        unsafe{
            &mut (*self.ptr)
        }
    }
}
struct Bar{
    v: i32
}

fn error()-> MutPtr<Bar> {
    let mut b = Bar{v:42};
    let ptr_b =  MutPtr::new(&mut b);
    ptr_b
}

fn main(){
    let mut b      = Bar{v:42};
    let mut ptr_b  = MutPtr::new(&mut b);
    let mut ptr_b1 = MutPtr::new(&mut b);

    ptr_b.v = 10;
    println!("{}",b.v);
    ptr_b1.v = 21;
    println!("{}",b.v);

    let mut err = error();
    println!("{}",err.v);
    err.v = 42; // what happens here?
    println!("{}",err.v);
}
```

On line 49 I am going to write to some memory address

```
err.v = 42;
```

I know that this is very bad, but I am wondering what actually happens? At first I expected it would crash but then I expected that I would be able to change the value at the address of err.v. But the write didn't do anything.

The memory seems to be write protected?

Was I just "lucky" that the write didn't change anything?

Comment: changing err.v works in the playpen... http://is.gd/CehSEO and yes, you just got lucky. if you run this without optimizations, nothing changes. since you set the pointer to some place in the stack inside a function, you probably didn't modify any memory that isn't overwritten before the next use. What you did was create undefined behavior which is very bad as you noted. Rust does not protect any memory from unsafe meddling.

Comment: also if you are interested in what's actually happening, you can generate LLVM-IR or asm code and analyze step by step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Was I just "lucky" that the write didn't change anything?

Yes, just lucky.

Writing to random memory is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior): the compiler assumes it never happens and optimises assuming this. If it does occur there's no limit or guarantees one can make about the resulting behaviour. E.g. it could [change the return address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming) used at the end of the next function call, making the CPU jump to some "random" piece of memory. It's generally really bad and such things are likely to be an exploitable security hole.

In the case, you've written, the lack of horrible program death is likely because `err` points lower down the stack, which the program isn't using at the point that the write happens. If the write happens while that area of the stack is being used, things like modifying pointers to point to nonsense can easily happen:

```
use std::mem;

#[inline(never)]
fn bad() -> &'static mut u32 {
    let mut x = 0u32;
    unsafe { mem::transmute(&mut x) }
}

#[inline(never)]
fn innocent(x: &mut u32) {
    println!("{:p}", &*x);
    *x = 0xDEADBEEF;

    println!("{:p}", x);
    *x = 0;
}

fn main() {
    let ptr = bad();
    innocent(ptr);
}
```

On [playpen](http://play.rust-lang.org/?run=1&code=use%20std%3A%3Amem%3B%0A%0A%23%5Binline%28never%29%5D%0Afn%20bad%28%29%20-%3E%20%26%27static%20mut%20u32%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20x%20%3D%200u32%3B%0A%20%20%20%20unsafe%20%7B%20mem%3A%3Atransmute%28%26mut%20x%29%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Binline%28never%29%5D%0Afn%20innocent%28x%3A%20%26mut%20u32%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%3Ap%7D%22%2C%20%26*x%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20*x%20%3D%200xDEADBEEF%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%3Ap%7D%22%2C%20x%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20*x%20%3D%200%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20ptr%20%3D%20bad%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20innocent%28ptr%29%3B%0A%7D) with `-O2`, at the moment, it prints:

```
0x7fff03dbae84
0xdeadbeef03dbae84
playpen: application terminated abnormally with signal 4 (Illegal instruction)
```

The first line is `x`s real value. The next line is `x` after `*x = 0xDEADBEEF;`... that is, that write was directly to the part of stack that was storing `x` itself, changing the upper half to `0xDEADBEEF`. At this point, `x` is a nonsense value, so the `*x = 0` causes a segfault (which manifests as an abort, due to Rust overriding some signal handlers by default).

I say "at the moment" because the behaviour of the program is very sensitive to the exact compiler versions/optimisation levels/source code, e.g. changing the first `print` to remove the `&*` makes the program print `0x7fff03dbae84` twice and then abort (likely because the return address is being modified rather than `x`).

If an attacker has any control over what gets written to an invalid pointer, they may/are likely to be able to modify the write pointer to cause the program to jump to a [piece of shellcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode) and pwn your application. I saw likely because [even the smallest "unexploitable" problems](http://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com.au/2014/08/the-poisoned-nul-byte-2014-edition.html) have been proved to be exploitable.